# TcxGrid com sub nível, mostrar coluna para expandir níveis na última posição

Tags: delphi, grid, devexpress

Ola! Sou iniciante com CxGrid, preciso fazer uma grid com sub nível, porém queria que a coluna que permite expandir os níveis (+) ficasse na última posição das colunas da grid. Não sei se é possível, efetuar tal modificação.
atualmente é mostrado da seguinte maneira:

[image: modo padrão]

precisaria efetuar algo semelhante ao seguinte:

[image: como desejo deixar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para manter um registro caso venha a ser útil, segundo o suporte DevExpress a versão atual não suporta esta funcionalidade.
segue resposta deles.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]